# Rank in Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For any linear system $Ax=b$, is it true that $\text{rank}(A|b)=\text{rank}(A)$ ?

It doesn't mention the dimension of both $A$ and $b$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I suspect that by $Ab$ OP means the adjoined matrix $(\,A\, | \,b\,)$, but certainly clarification would be helpful...

Comment: The ranks are the same if and only if the system has a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect, in general. It is true only when $b$ is in the range or column space of the operator $A$, i.e., if the system $Ax=b$ has at least one solution. For instance, consider
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \text{ and }b = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$
We have $\text{rank}(A) = 1$, whereas $\text{rank}(A \vert b) = 2$.